# Return a parent dictionary if substring inside a nested dictionary value exist?

Tags: python, dictionary, search, substring

How to return "key_three" Only after searching for a substring "Iron Man" inside the nested somedict. The objective is if `"Iron man"` is found return all of the entire parent dictionary type value of "key_three" [key] [dictionary having ->** ] i.e. `including key_three_one:[values], key_three_two:[values]` and the third dictionary-element **{}**.

```
somedict = [
               {
                  "anyKey":1,
                  "key_two":2,
                  **{            #key_three/value of key_three is nothing but a dictionary.
                    key_three_one: "spiderman",
                    key_three_two:"superman",
                    "key_three_three":{
                         "from_asguard" : "is not Iron Man:batman"
                    }
                  }**
    }]
```

I have already gone through these links : 
1. [Python return dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33726641/python-return-dictionary)
2. [Iterate through a nested Dictionary and Sub Dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41269633/iterate-through-a-nested-dictionary-and-sub-dictionary-in-python)
3. [Loop through all nested dictionary values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756427/loop-through-all-nested-dictionary-values)
4. [Python function return dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41267719/python-function-return-dictionary).

Comment: So visiting all the links, you must have written some code. Can you please share your efforts, to see that you tried to come to a solution on your own.

Comment: `code`
`# n = len(somedict)`
x = 0
y = 0
# for x in range(n):
    # x +=1
`for eachvalue in somedict[:][:]:
    x+=1
    #print(eachvalue)
    for key,value in eachvalue[0].items():
        #print(key,value)
        if 'Iron Man:' in str(value) :
            print(value)
            y+=1
        
print("\n\n\n", x)
print("\n\n\n", y)`

IGNORE X and Y

Comment: Do not use comments for code, please. Edit your question instead. Ideally, your question should be self-contained, thus contain all the required information to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

iterate through items of the dictionary inside your `somedict` list,

```
for key,value in somedict[0].items():
    if 'Iron Man' in str(value):
        print(key, value)

>>>key_three {'inside_key_three': {'from_asguard': 'is not Iron Man'}}
```

or you can use list comprehension:

```
[{k:v} for k,v in somedict[0].items() if 'Iron Man' in str(v)]

>>>[{'key_three': {'inside_key_three': {'from_asguard': 'is not Iron Man'}}}]
```

Comment: This helps but not what i was expecting, still looking for answers.